# PHP Non-String URL/HTML Safety

Tags: php, html, url, types, escaping

### Question

**Is there any other [variable type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) that are unsafe to print to HTML pages or URLs without escaping?** (*ignoring objects with custom toString methods*).

### Background

I'm writing an internal library to magically sanitize anything (simple strings, ints, floats, etc., arrays, nested arrays, objects, ...) given the data's destination (either to a HTML page or a URL).

For strings, it's obvious that I have to apply [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and/or [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for certain strings.

I'd like to preserve the type of variable if possible, so I'd like to not have to convert ints, floats, etc. if possible.

### Sample Code

Here's the current state of part of my class **(please note that the code below does not account for object functions and properties yet!)**

```
class HogwartsExpress {
    private static $URL = 0;
    private static $HTML = 1;

    // ...

    private static function escape_array($arr, $method){
        $escaped_arr = array();
        foreach ($arr as $k=>$v){
            $safe_k = self::escape_non_array($k, $method);
            $escaped_arr[$safe_k] = is_array($v) ? self::escape_array($v, $method): self::escape_non_array($v, $method);
        }
        return $escaped_arr;
    }

    private static function escape_non_array($val, $method){
        if (is_string($val)){
            switch ($method){
                case self::$URL:  return urlencode($val);
                case self::$HTML: return htmlspecialchars($val);
            }
        }
        else {
            return $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that no one had experience with this or that the search terms I used were not the right ones, so I decided to do some research.

## Yes, in a few cases.

Cases to consider when sanitizing output variables:

- Nested array elements
- Object functions and properties
- Resources (unsafe in URL)

### Safe characters for certain contexts

#### [URL (urlencode)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced ...

**Safe characters**: 0-9 A-Z a-z - _ .

#### [HTML (htmlspecialchars)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

> The translations performed are:
>
> - '&' (ampersand) becomes '&'
> - '"' (double quote) becomes '"' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
> - "'" (single quote) becomes ''' (or ') only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
> - '<' (less than) becomes '<'
> - '>' (greater than) becomes '>'

**Unsafe characters**: & " ' < >

### Non-string variable types

#### [Boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

```
// boolean (TRUE|FALSE)
echo TRUE;  //1
echo FALSE; //
```

**Possible Characters**: 1

#### [Integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

```
// decimal non-zero /[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*/
echo 1;       //1
echo 83;      //83
echo -7;      //-7
echo +30;     //30

// decimal zero     /[+-]0/
echo 0;       //0
echo +0;      //0
echo -0;      //0

// hexadecimal      /[+-]?0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/
echo 0x0;     //0
echo -0x0;    //0
echo 0x0A;    //10
echo -0X13;   //-19
echo +0x22;   //34

// octal            /[+-]?0[0-7]+/
echo 00;      //0
echo -00;     //0
echo +00;     //0
echo 07;      //7
echo 09;      //0
echo -02;     //-2
echo 020;     //16
echo +015;    //13

// binary           /[+-]?0b[01]/
echo 0b0;     //0
echo +0b0;    //0
echo -0b0;    //0
echo 0b111;   //7
echo -0b101;  //-5
echo +0b1101; //13
```

**Possible Characters**: 0-9 -

#### [Floating Point Number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

```
// Float /[+-]?({REQ}|(({OPT}\.{REQ})|({REQ}\.{OPT})))[eE][+-]?{REQ}/
// OPT   /[0-9]*/
// REQ   /[0-9]+/
echo .53;   //0.53
echo 42;    //42
echo 64.;   //64
echo 25.11; //25.11
echo -5.2;  //-5.2
echo +8.8;  //8.8
echo -3.2E1 //-32
echo +2.e-2 //0.02
```

**Possible Characters**: 0-9 - .

#### [Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
echo array('a' => 3.2, 'b' => 5); //Array
$foo = array('bar' => '<');
echo $foo['bar'];                 //<
```

**Main Output**: Array

**Inner Output**: Nested element (each nested element needs to be checked - see question source code.)

#### [Object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)

```
class Foo {}
echo new Foo(); //{error}

class Bird {
    function __construct() { $this->beak_len = 3.5; echo 'hoot'; }
    function __toString(){ return 'hedwig'; }
    function tweet(){ echo 'HOOT'; }
}
$owl = new Bird();   //hoot
echo $owl;           //hedwig
$owl->tweet();       //HOOT
echo $owl->beak_len; //3.5
```

**Output sources**: constructor, __toString, other functions, properties (each must be checked)

#### [Resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

It seems unlikely to have to print a resource, but some info is provided here for the sake of completeness.

[List of resource types](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php)

```
$doc = xml_parser_create();
echo $doc;                  //Resource id #4
$tmp = tmpfile();
echo $tmp;                  //Resource id #4
```

**Output**: Resource ID #[0-9] (the # is not safe in URLs)

#### [NULL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php)

```
// NULL
echo NULL; // {null}
```

**Output**: